# Checking file extension and mimetype doesn't work on text files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to verify the file extension and mime type in order to prevent users to upload non allowed type of files to the node.js server here is the code i used :

```
function checkFileType(file, cb) {
  // Allowed ext
  const filetypes = /csv|json|txt/;
  // Check ext
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  // Check mime
  console.log(file.mimetype); // text/plain
  console.log(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if (mimetype && extname) {
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb("Error: CSV Or Text Files Only!");
  }
}
```

This works perfectly for CSV and JSON type of files but for some reason whenever I upload a text file it doesn't I did some debugging and it turns out the following line returns False.

`const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());`

The documentation of the test method says "Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether or not a pattern exists in a searched string."

the txt pattern clearly exists in the searched string, so what am missing here?

Comment: Did you _verify_ that `path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase()` returned what you think it should in the first place?

Comment: Yes it returns .txt

Comment: This is a weird question. You've checked the returned type in the console, and found out that it's "text/plain". How can you expect the given regexp to match that?

Comment: What @Teemu said: `const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);` – this will of course be false, because you are testing whether `text/plain` contains `txt` here. It doesn’t. For CSV, you likely got mime type as `application/csv` or `text/csv`, the check for `csv` works with that. And same thing for `application/json` and looking for `json`.

Comment: i see @CBroe i added `const filetypes = /csv|json|txt|text/;` and that fixes the problem is there a better solution though ?

Comment: Not exactly related, but you should test against full mimetypes, if the filename itself contains the letters "txt" (ex. txtfile.jpg), your test can give false positives. And when you're testing the extension names, you should check also, that the tested extension is the very last part of the filename.

Comment: @Teemu great suggestion to point out, thank you

Comment: Also, detecting a .csv is more complicated, because its mimetype might vary depending on which application originally created the file. If you'll create a csv file with a text editor, you'll most likely get `text/plain` as the mimetype.

Comment: I see, any idea on how exactly I can detect the CSV even those created in a text editor like you pointed out cause miss detecting the file type that could break the app later for me

Comment: I don’t think this has so much to do with what editor created the file. With a file upload, the browser will determine what Content-Type header to send, based on the association of the file suffix with a particular mime type on the OS level, I think. (So from a system that has _never_ handled any `.csv` type, in a way that associates suffix that with any spreadsheet program, you might still get `text/plain`, or maybe even `application/octet-stream`.)

Comment: You can also try to _determine_ the mime type on the server, there’s libraries that try and determine that based on the file content. That might still get you `text/plain` for CSV files though, because that’s basically what they _are_. There are no specific initial byte sequences to look for like with images for example, so this _can_ only be guessed.

Comment: @CBroe I actually meant, that it's hard to recognize csv files. `File.mimetype` property is quite new, it's not even documented on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) yet, and perhaps even not widely supported. I made a small test, I created a csv with Excel, in Chrome and FF `File.mimetype` was `undefined`, and `File.type` returned "application/vnd.ms-excel". For a csv file created with Notepad++ the values were the same. Hence, like you've explained in the comment, the mimetype comes from  the OS, not from the application created the file, which was my lesson today.